# How to add attachment to wp_mail from wordpress' media uploader? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am developing a plugin where i have a backend-page which shows a input text-field and a button. When you click on that button, wordpress' media uploader opens and you can choose a file. The URL of that file will be inserted into that input fields value. Here you can see the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wp-uploader">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="" />
    <input class="button" id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Legg til PDF fra mediabibliotek" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Velg en PDF',
            button: {
                text: 'Velg'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
```

I would like to achive that this chosen file will be sent as attachment of wp_mail.

Here is my function:

```
function dd_send_email(){

    $email_sent = false;

    // get email template data
    $email_template_object = dd_get_current_options();
    $url = $_POST['upload_image'];
    $mail_attachment = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR=>$url);    

    // if email template data was found
    if ( !empty( $email_template_object ) ):

        // setup wp_mail headers
        $wp_mail_headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        // use wp_mail to send email
        $email_sent = wp_mail( array( 'example@email.com') , $email_template_object['dd_emne_forhaandsbestilling'], $email_template_object['dd_email_text_forhaandsbestilling'], $wp_mail_headers, $mail_attachment );
    endif;

    return $email_sent;

}
```

But this is not working. I still get emails without any attachment. I guess the way im getting the file-url is wrong but i couldn't find out how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could send the url that points to the file you've uploaded (something in your `uploads/` folder), but I don't really know how one would send a file this way.

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to achive. But how do i get this url?

Comment: Well since you're putting the url in an input field, on submit all the input variables should be available in the `$_POST` global variable. In your case this should be in the `$_POST['upload_image']` variable. So you can try with `$mail_attachment = $_POST['upload_image']`. This is off the top of my head...

Comment: @dingo_d Thanks for your replies. I have tried this out but it still isn't working.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that you need to have form for it to work :\ Check `$_REQUEST` variable, maybe it's hiding there somewhere...

Comment: Show the code that's calling dd_send_email.  More information is needed.  It looks like you have a lot of proper things, but check (using firebug or some console) to make sure the value of #upload_image is actually getting changed when a user uploads an image.  Also, you may need to pass $_POST['upload_image'] to the function rather than relying on $_POST.  It depends how and when the function is called.

Comment: @DanielC here is the code which is calling dd_send_email. if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {                                                       $email_sent = dd_send_email();
if( !email_sent ): // email could not be sent - alert
else: // email could be sent - alert
endif;
}

Comment: @DanielC i have checked the value of #upload_image. If i choose an image, i can see the url in the text-field but if i check the HTML the value-attribute is still empty.

Comment: If the value-attribute is still empty, it looks as though your `$('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);` may not be working.  Try doing a console.log( attachment ) after you assign it to see if everything is in order there.  If that looks right, then do a var_dump of $_POST inside your dd_send_email function to see what values are being passed through the submit.  You can even var_dump right before you call the function to make sure $_POST is populated proper before you enter the function.

Comment: @DanielC when i  do console.log(attachment) i get the file path in the url. So that looks fine. And when i do var_dump($_POST) i do get this: array(2) { ["upload_image"]=> string(68) "http://localhost/norskeanalyser/wp-content/uploads/Testanalyse-2.pdf" ["submit"]=> string(17) "Send aksjeanalyse" }. 
That looks also fine. How can i pass this file-path to the wp-mail attachment? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found the answer by myself. Because wp_mail needs the file path like this /uploads/2016/03/example.jpg we have to convert our url to a path like this.

I did achive this by changing the following in `dd_send_mail()` and thought i can share it with you:

```
// change url to path   
$dd_url = $_POST['upload_image'];
$dd_path = parse_url($dd_url);

// cut the path to right directory
$array = explode("/norskeanalyser/wp-content", $dd_path['path']);
unset($array[0]);
$text = implode("/", $array);
```

and then i did save the `$text` into `$mail_attachment` and called it in wp_mail like above.

Thanks to everyone for great help!